# Adding scroll up to animated panel

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-animate

I have created a panel that animates down on a click using:

```
 <script>
function toggleSlider() {
    if ($("#panelThatSlides").is(":visible")) {
        $("#contentThatFades").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $("#panelThatSlides").slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#panelThatSlides").slideDown(600, function(){
            $("#contentThatFades").animate(
                {

                 opacity: "1",
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}
</script>
```

This works great, however when it animates down for some screen sizes you can't see the content (it is below the browser bottom edge). What I need to do is to also make the page scroll up at the same time - any ideas? yhx

Comment: Post your `HTML` too.

Comment: And also you don't need to make this code so long. Just use jquery `slideToggle` function.

Answer (score 1):

The basic function you need is:

```
$('html,body').animate({ 
  scrollTop: $('#panelThatSlides').offset().top 
}, 600);
```

> **UPDATE:**

Just add an id [`id="sliderbtn"`] to your anchor and remove `onclick` event.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="toggleSlider();"><img alt="" src="/images/css/blind.jpg" /></a>
```

Update your javascript with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sliderbtn").click(function () {
if ($("#panelThatSlides").is(":visible")) {
    $("#contentThatFades").animate(
        {
            opacity: "0"
        },
        600,
        function(){
            $("#panelThatSlides").slideUp();
        }
    );
}
else {
    $("#panelThatSlides").slideDown(600, function(){
        $("#contentThatFades").animate(
            {
                opacity: "1"
            },
            600
        );
        $('html,body').animate({ 
         scrollTop: $('#panelThatSlides').offset().top 
        }, 600);
    });
}  
});
});
```

See if this was what you wanted. :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I can't seem to get that to work? The animation and fade in is what we wanted for the panel - I just need to add the scroll down function to it you can see here: www.employeefinder.co.uk

Comment: Bhorer_Alo Thanks you for your help I have made the change I *think* you suggested but it doesn't seem to work. I'm sorry :) what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See a live demo of your site with this code, working.

http://employeefinder.hostei.com

Comment: You are awesome thanks for you help! :) - I have got this working now Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: If you think this is the answer you were looking for, you should select it as accepted. :)